# localStorage - Detectar cambios manualmente

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

¡Buenas noches para todos!

Espero que estén bastante bien.
Verán, tengo la duda si es posible detectar cambios del localStorage, como por ejemplo, el cambio manual de algún JSON proveniente de este desde el inspector del navegador, y si es posible, cómo le puedo decir a mi aplicativo qué hubo un cambio en el localStorage de forma repentina?

No sé si esto sirva, pero estoy usando Angular 12 y ando haciendo practicas con el localStorage. ¿Angular incluye alguna funcionalidad qué me ayude a detectar dichos cambios?

¡Muchas gracias! Todas sus respuestas son de gran ayuda. ^^

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado / averiguado? ¿Cuál es el problema específico? Tal como está redactada tu pregunta, es muy amplia, lo que ocasionaría su cierre. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Encontre que existe una [forma de responder a los cambios de la memoria con el StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#responder_a_cambios_en_la_memoria_con_el_evento_storageevent)

Este evento no detecta los **sessionStorage**, asímismo no responde a los cambios de la misma página, si lo pruebas en **otra página te funcionará correctamente**.

Aqui dejo un ejemplo de uso:

Cree una variable LocalStorage denominada `name`:

[image: variable LocalStorage name]

Aquí hago el llamado del evento `StorageEvent`:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    
    // TODO: Algunos valores útiles { key, newValue, oldvalue } = e;
});
```

[image: console.log de StorageEvent]

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos .